# Disable CSS and Javascript cache in nginx server created with Docker

Tags: php, nginx, docker

I've got nginx server created with Docker. When I'm making changes to JS or CSS file, those appear after 30 - 60 seconds with force-refreshing in the browser (yes, browser cache is turned off). How to make them appear immediately? My system is Ubuntu 17.

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log off;
  error_log off;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
  open_file_cache max=100;
  client_max_body_size 4M;
}

daemon off;
```

**And the server config:**

```
server {
    server_name l.site;
    root /var/www/site;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        if (!-f $request_filename){
                set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
        }
        if (!-d $request_filename){
            set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
        }
        if ($request_filename !~ "-l"){
            set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
        }
        if ($rule_0 = "321"){
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
        }
    }

    # from UPDATE #1 ->
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      expires off;

      # don't cache it
      proxy_no_cache 1;

      # even if cached, don't try to use it
      proxy_cache_bypass 1;
    }
    # <- from UPDATE #1

    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/site_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site_access.log;
}
```

**UPDATE #1**

Added this to server and still it is not showing me updated files in the browser just after code change.

```
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
  expires off;

  # don't cache it
  proxy_no_cache 1;

  # even if cached, don't try to use it
  proxy_cache_bypass 1;
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

Used [THIS](https://ryanclouser.com/2015/07/16/nginx-Disable-Caching/) configuration, and still... didn't helped.

```
location / {
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    expires off;
}
```

Link to newest versions of files:
https://gist.github.com/ktrzos/1bbf2fd0161ce0e20541ccb18fe066a5

Comment: sometimes cache is not a bad thing, what about consider to add somthing like  ```code.js?<some_rand_value>```

Comment: I didn't write that cache is a bad thing :). I even think on the opposite way about that topic. It's just not needed for me on the development environment. 
What is the `code.js` thingy?

Comment: Code.js is just any file you dont want to be cached

Comment: Oohh... I thought this is some kind of external library :D. My bad. Been trying this way at the beginning of these problems. Also not working :/.

Comment: If so,  it looks it does not related to ngx settings then.

Comment: Interesting. So, maybe u know what else could be not as it should be here?

Comment: Do you send a query from the same host as a docker image running?

Comment: Could you try to send a query inside a docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable cache using .htaccess. this is code from my live website. this should work.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Check my updated question, please. I need to have ability to immediately check changes made in project on my development server and not to wait a half minute to make it happen. This is very frustrating.

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos I have updated the answer. Please check

Comment: Does `.htaccess` files are used by Apache and not Nginx?

Comment: And I have Nginx. Also, already used [THIS](https://ryanclouser.com/2015/07/16/nginx-Disable-Caching/) and didn't worked....

Answer (score 0):

When using docker on VM (VirtualBox or so) change nginx.conf property `sendfile` to off

```
http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile off;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log off;
  error_log off;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
  open_file_cache max=100;
  client_max_body_size 4M;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've got that property on `off` value. [HERE](https://gist.github.com/ktrzos/1bbf2fd0161ce0e20541ccb18fe066a5) you got the latest versions of my nginx config files.